# modal won't close on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JS modal (no jquery), since I have some issues with that approach...

Everything works good except that on mobile user can't close it.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

It is probably related to that touch that I'm missing...

I tried with jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(modal).on('click touchstart', function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

The problem here is that if user clicks inside the modal, it will also disappear...

What I need is that when user clicks only outside, modal should disappear...

Any ideas how can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a JQuery solution? Or would you rather stick to pure JS?

Comment: I just need it to work :-)

Answer (score 0):

instead of registering click on the target, register on the document and then check to see that the mouse wasn't inside of the target

```
$(document).on ('mouseup touchstart', function (e)
{
    var container = $("#myModal");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't worry about desktop, I have two themes (mobile and desktop), so desktop is working... I only need to make it working on mobile...

Comment: I was just curious if it was the fact that it's on mobile that breaks it, or if there is something wrong with the logic

Comment: That first thing is what is working for desktop... but I must change something for mobile in order to work...

Comment: I understand that. I'm trying to help but to diagnose why this isn't working it would be really helpful to know if it's not working because of the fact that it's on mobile

Comment: ok, so I just replaced my previous code with this on desktop and it doesn't work...

Comment: I think the issue could be that mobile platforms are looking for css `cursor:pointer`. Perhaps you could edit `$(document).css()` when they open the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `contains` ?

I just tested it on iOS safari and chrome, it works correctly

please check out the demo,

when you click the yellow part, it still exists

however, when you click the pink part, the whole modal will hide

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/wasoponoye/edit?html,css,js,output)

code in JS Bin

```
var pa = document.querySelector('#modal-overlay');
var ch = document.querySelector('#modal-container');

pa.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!ch.contains(e.target)) {
    pa.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the 'mousedown' event on the document, then check if the modal is in the event path. If it's not, then hide the modal. If it is, then do nothing.

```js
var myModal = document.getElementById('myModal');

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e)
{
    if (e.path.indexOf(myModal) == -1)
    myModal.hidden = true;
});
```

Comment: I get this here when I run this: "TypeError: e.path is undefined"

Comment: Ok - after further digging it looks like event.path is only supported in Chrome. I tested this on mobile Chrome and it worked but I am not sure about the support in mobile Safari. Other folks have discussed this, e.g. https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1563 There is a nice workaround in there as well which you might want to try.